# How do I download PHP 5.2.17 OFFLINE on Windows Server 2012

Tags: php, web-platform-installer, microsoft-web-platform

I am currently trying to figure out a way to install PHP 5.2.17 on a production server we currently have. How can I go about this?

I have tried `WebPICMD.exe /Offline /Products:PHP52 /Path:C:\webpioff`, but this does not provide a PHP 5.2 version.. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? And of course, why are you trying to install an ancient unsupported PHP version?

Comment: @MichaelHampton , It does not provide a PHP52 installer. Not my choice, we currently have a legacy app that is 5.2 version.

Comment: It's probably much too old. You will almost certainly have to fix the legacy app (which should have been done years ago, but someone decided to procrastinate)...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by downloading a msi file corresponding to the version I needed and moving it to the offline server.

When installing, make sure to include the ext and other folders as it might be "X"-ed out.

https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/